# Scale-play response jsondata to view List

Tags: scala, playframework, jackson, ws-client

[image]

I got json data using ws.
And then we will
 want to display it in a list format in view.
I do not know how to do it.
Please help me!

*MyGoal:

[image]

Comment: Could you please explain your goal a bit more clearly? What you want is to display your data in a neat way, is it right?

Comment: @if(events) {
        <table>
               @for((event) <- events){
               <tr>
                 <td>@event.eventId</td>
               </tr>
             }

Comment: ...is this supposed to be an answer to my comment?

Comment: I want to add json's data to @event.eventId

Comment: You don't need `Json.toJson(response.json)` as `response.json` is Json already (and for `Ok(Json.toJson(json))`, `json` will be Json too)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I may have misunderstood your question, but sounds like you want a browser page to view the data? You will need to define a view to display it in, and then invoke this view with the Ok method. For example, in your controller, replacing `Ok(Json.toJson(json))` with `Ok(views.html.messages(Messages))` and creating the file messages.scala.html in the views package, which looks something like:

```
@(messages:List[Message]) {
  <table class="table table-striped">
  @messages.map { message =>
    <tr>
      <td>@message.id</td>
      <td>@message.text</td>
      ...
    </tr>
  }
  </table>
}
```

Anything beginning with @ is a scala expression. Use a template functions to decorate or standardise your pages, see [Playframework Template Use Cases](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaTemplateUseCases)

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific.

Comment: Please check once even after modifying the contents.

Comment: Have you created temp.scala.html in the views package? If so, show us the listing. Eclipse may still show an error even if it is there. (By the way, it's easier if you show your code in the question rather than showing images).

Comment: I succeeded.Thank you very much

Comment: Glad to hear it! 再見